# How to extract multiple CSV data sets from textfile with SAS?

Tags: csv, sas

I have a file with this format

```
Text1
Men
2018
Text3
Text4
1,Age;2,AB;3,Januar;4,Februar;5,März;6,April;7,Mai;8,Juni;9,Juli;10,August;11,September;12,Oktober;13,November;14,Dezember;15,1.1.Jahr
0;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
1;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
2;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
3;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
4;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
5;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00


Text1
Women
2018
Text3
Text4
1,Age;2,AB;3,Januar;4,Februar;5,März;6,April;7,Mai;8,Juni;9,Juli;10,August;11,September;12,Oktober;13,November;14,Dezember;15,1.1.Jahr
0;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
1;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
2;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
3;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
4;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
5;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00;0,00
```

How can I extract the csv-blocks and save them as two separate sas datasets (one for men and one for women)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Looks like a pretty simple pattern. Just write a data step to read it.  What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Don't see why you would need to separate it into multiple files. Just read it as it is.
You can make up better names for the variables if you want.  Looks like there are 5 lines of text, a header row, and then multiple lines of data.  Separate sections are separated by blank lines.

```
data want ;
  infile have dsd dlm=';' truncover ;
  length text1-text5 $100 var1-var15 8 ;
  retain hunt 1 text1-text5;
  if hunt then do;
    do until (_infile_ ne ' ');
      input @;
      if _infile_=' ' then input;
    end;
    input (text1-text5) ($100. /)/ ;
    hunt=0;
  end;
  else do;
    input @;
    if _infile_ ne ' ' then do;
      input (var1-var15) (:commax.);
      output;
    end;
    else hunt=1;
  end;
  drop hunt;
run;
```

Result:

```
      t      t     t      t      t                               v  v  v  v  v  v
      e      e     e      e      e    v  v  v  v  v  v  v  v  v  a  a  a  a  a  a
 O    x      x     x      x      x    a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  a  r  r  r  r  r  r
 b    t      t     t      t      t    r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  r  1  1  1  1  1  1
 s    1      2     3      4      5    1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5

 1  Text1  Men    2018  Text3  Text4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 2  Text1  Men    2018  Text3  Text4  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 3  Text1  Men    2018  Text3  Text4  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 4  Text1  Men    2018  Text3  Text4  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 5  Text1  Men    2018  Text3  Text4  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 6  Text1  Men    2018  Text3  Text4  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 7  Text1  Women  2018  Text3  Text4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 8  Text1  Women  2018  Text3  Text4  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 9  Text1  Women  2018  Text3  Text4  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10  Text1  Women  2018  Text3  Text4  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
11  Text1  Women  2018  Text3  Text4  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12  Text1  Women  2018  Text3  Text4  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```